# How to send body to simulate_post in Falcon

Tags: python-3.x, testing, falconframework

```
def test_with_invalid_param(self):
        body = urlencode({
            "email":"jit",
            "password":"ewr"
        })
        result = self.simulate_post(self.path, body=body, headers=self.headers)
        print(result.json)
        self.assertEqual(result.status, "201 OK")
```

I am getting json decode error from Falcon server.

I am have implemented a middleware to decode json.

```
try:
                req.data = json.loads(req.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))
                return
            except:
                raise falcon.HTTPBadRequest(
                    "Bad request", "Invalid body. Unable to parse the given content"
                )
```

Can anyone spot what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

From this [Github issue](https://github.com/falconry/falcon/issues/694#issuecomment-175939219), looks like you need to set the `Content-Type`:

```
body = urlencode({
            'username': 'new_user',
            'email': 'email',
            'password': 'password',
            'location': 'Tucson, AZ'
        })
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
self.simulate_post(self.entry_path, body=body, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I am still getting the middleware exception "Bad request", "Invalid body. Unable to parse the given content"

Answer (score 1):

Try using a bounded stream:
https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.bounded_stream

Your code would look like this:
`req.data = json.loads(req.bounded_stream.read().decode("utf-8"))`